# Subset a data frame to include only rows which include a certain obs

Tags: grep

I have a data frame including a column of values with either a "name" starting with `a` or starting with a number. The column is a character variable. How can I subset the data frame to include only variables starting with `a`?

Sample row:

```
name
a141975
a2348970283
234:28943:885
43:345753:45
a28734
a4874
a298592
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really just asking for this or do I not understand your question correctly?

```
$ cat data.txt
name
a141975
a2348970283
234:28943:885
43:345753:45
a28734
a4874
a298592

$ grep '^a' data.txt
a141975
a2348970283
a28734
a4874
a298592
```